# Re-establish route to localhost on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, routing, localhost, windows-networking

> route -f

How do you re-establish a route to `localhost` after this? I can re-establish connections to the Internet via wireless using

```
route add {wirelessgateway} {wirelessip} if {wirelessif}
route add 0.0.0.0 {wirelessgateway}
```

but a lot of things fail because there is no route to `127.0.0.1`. Also, Internet access via the browser is very slow, while Internet access via programs like telnet does not work.

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you run route -f? The quickest way to restore things is to restart the PC - this will restore all dynamic routing info.